# Gram-Schmidt question with just 2 vectors. Process not working, resulting vectors not orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

So this is what I have so far. Just two vectors trying to make an orthogonal basis out of them using Gram-Schmidt but when I inner product the results it isn't zero.

Here is what I have so far. Given vectors (both already normalized) are:
$$
\begin{align*}
v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)
&&v_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}$$

So let $x_1=v_1$ thus using Gram-Schmidt, $x_2$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
x_2&=v_2-\frac{v_2\cdot x_1}{x_1\cdot x_1}x_1\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)-
\Bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)^*\cdot
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)
\Bigg]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\1
\end{array}\right)-
\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\-i\\2
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}\\
$$

But when I do the inner product with $x_1$ and $x_2$ I don't get zero, instead I get

$$
\begin{align*}
x_1\cdot x_2 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)^*\cdot
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\-i\\2
\end{array}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left(\begin{array}{c}
i\\1\\0
\end{array}\right)^*\cdot
\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\-i\\2
\end{array}\right)\\
&=-i
\end{align*}
$$

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

For the complex inner product, note that $v_2\cdot x_1$ is not the same as $x_1\cdot v_2$: they are complex conjugates of each other. Here, you ended up using the wrong one (apparently) when you found that dot product to be equal to $\frac i2$. If you instead use $-\frac i2$, you'll get a resulting $x_2$ that is indeed orthogonal to $x_1$.

(In particular, you used $v_2^*x_1$ to calculate $v_2\cdot x_1$, but I think the right definition is $x_1^*v_2$.)

Comment: So you are saying the G-S should be defined as this instead? $$x_2=v_2-\frac{x_1\cdot v_2}{x_1\cdot x_1}x_1$$? (IE just reverse the order of the inner product on the projection term)

Comment: You should either reverse the order of the inner product, or modify the definition of inner product, but not both!